# mySQL - double sum with join statement and format table

Tags: mysql

I just can not get my code working when I join two tables with sum.

First table

```
create table table1 (
code int(10) primary key,
PN varchar(10) not null,
LOC varchar(10) not null,
Stock int(10) not null);

insert into table1 values (1,'T1','AAA',2);
insert into table1 values (2,'A1','AAA',2);
insert into table1 values (3,'J1','AAA',3);
insert into table1 values (4,'A2','AAA',1);
insert into table1 values (5,'J2','BBB',2);
insert into table1 values (6,'A3','BBB',3);
insert into table1 values (7,'J3','BBB',4);
insert into table1 values (8,'T1','BBB',5);
insert into table1 values (9,'A1','BBB',1);
insert into table1 values (10,'J2','CCC',3);
insert into table1 values (11,'J2','DDD',4);
insert into table1 values (12,'A1','DDD',3);
insert into table1 values (13,'J2','EEE',5);
insert into table1 values (14,'A1','AAA',15);
```

Second table

```
create table table2 (
code int(10) primary key,
PN varchar(10) not null,
LOC varchar(10) not null,
Used int(10) not null,
Year int(10));

insert into table2 values (1,'T1','AAA',2, 2018);
insert into table2 values (2,'A1','AAA',2, 2018);
insert into table2 values (3,'J1','AAA',3,2017);
insert into table2 values (4,'A2','AAA',1,2018);
insert into table2 values (5,'J2','BBB',2,2017);
insert into table2 values (6,'A3','BBB',3,2017);
insert into table2 values (7,'J3','BBB',4,2016);
insert into table2 values (8,'T1','BBB',5,2016);
insert into table2 values (9,'A1','BBB',1,2018);
insert into table2 values (10,'J2','CCC',3,2018);
insert into table2 values (11,'J2','DDD',4,2018);
insert into table2 values (12,'A1','DDD',3,2018);
insert into table2 values (13,'J2','EEE',5,2017);
insert into table2 values (14,'A1','AAA',15,2018);
```

I want to print results in the below format for all locations. I can get the totals as per below but when I use CASE WHEN it duplicates values.

```
+------+----+-----+-------+------------+------------+
| code | PN | LOC | Stock | counttotal | TotalStock |
+------+----+-----+-------+------------+------------+
|    2 | A1 | AAA |     2 |         16 |         84 |
|    4 | A2 | AAA |     1 |          1 |          1 |
|    5 | J2 | BBB |     2 |          8 |         28 |
|    1 | T1 | AAA |     2 |          2 |          7 |
+------+----+-----+-------+------------+------------+

SELECT a.*,
Count(b.Used) as counttotal,
sum(a.Stock) TotalStock
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b on a.PN=b.PN WHERE b.Year > 2017
GROUP BY a.PN
ORDER BY a.PN ASC;
```

However, as oppose to total for all LOC I want to have just below columns with correct data.

```
+----+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| PN | AAA_Used | AAA_Stock | BBB_Used | BBB_Stock |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| A1 |       68 |        68 |        4 |         4 |
| A2 |        1 |         1 |        0 |         0 |
| J2 |        0 |         0 |        0 |         4 |
| T1 |        4 |         2 |        0 |         5 |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+

SELECT a.PN

,SUM(CASE WHEN b.LOC = "AAA" THEN b.Used ELSE 0 END) AS "AAA_Used"
,SUM(CASE WHEN a.LOC = "AAA" THEN a.Stock ELSE 0 END) AS "AAA_Stock"
,SUM(CASE WHEN b.LOC = "BBB" THEN b.Used ELSE 0 END) AS "BBB_Used"
,SUM(CASE WHEN a.LOC = "BBB" THEN a.Stock ELSE 0 END) AS "BBB_Stock"

FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b on a.PN=b.PN WHERE b.Year > 2017
GROUP BY a.PN, b.PN
ORDER BY a.PN ASC;
```

Comment: Why can't you compute this pivot in the application layer? Doing it in SQL is extraordinarily messy.

Comment: First of all, neither of your queries are correct, they only run in MySQL under certain sql mode settings (only full group by not set). For example, in the first output for PN=A1, LOC is only AAA, while your data has AAA, BBB and DDD LOC values as well associated with A1.

Comment: Secondly, when you join two tables, then the join combines all records with matching values, which will lead to duplications - as you can see here. Remove the group by and the sums to see what I mean.

Comment: @tadman - if it was easy i would not ask for help. Shadow - removing GROUP BY and SUM make no sense for my problem. Anyone with any idea please?

Comment: You're taking the hard approach, doing it in SQL, which is why it's not easy. If you're manipulating arrays in the application layer it's *considerably* easier, which is why I mention this. Do you have one? If so, what language is it in?